# How MPI peer-node communiate with each other?

Tags: mpi

Consider there are three nodes whose hostnames are host-master, host-slave1, host-slave2 respectively.

Let the MPI program to be run on host-master, with the executing command like this:
`mpiexec -n 4 -h host-master,host-slave1,host-slave2  mpi.program`

Since MPI APIs (e.g. MPI_Send/MPI_Bcast/..) can be invoked to transfer messages between two different nodes (for example, host-slave1 -> host-slave2),

I don't know what kind of OS communication interfaces that MPI-Engine use to implement this.

By createing tcp-socket between host-slave1 and host-slave2, and sending messages throught this channel?

Or by host-master collecting messages from host-slave1 through pipe channel, then forwarding these messages to host-slave2 through pipe as well?

Comment: That question is too broad. There are many different communication backends in the MPI implementations - none of which is described by the MPI standard. Please narrow the question down towards a specific MPI implementation and context.

Comment: So how MPI_Send communicate between two ranks? By createing new TCP socket(if so, which one is TCP server and which TCP port to bind and listen)?